# How to persist context for more databricks jobs

Tags: databricks, workflow, azure-databricks

is it possible to run two jobs in databricks workflow and save context? I tried to use environmental variable in one job, but when I run second job, the env does not exists (using same cluster, but new spark submit).

Other thing I came up with, is to use DBFS file, or maybe secret...

I cannot use tasks withing one job, hence tasks cannot be run immediately each after.

Comment: You can try creating temporary views in order to achieve this. Store the required data in a temporary view and access it when ever required.

Comment: The temporary view, isn't it available only in session? Creating a view is possible. But would be nice not to access a hive or so, it would complicate the CI/CD pipeline. So far, I have used locked DBFS file, it is accessible via databricks CLI, which is quite convinient.